# Как получить список публичных полей класса?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Например

```
class A {
  x;
  y;
  constructor() {
    this.x=0
    this.y=0
  }
}
```

Как получить `['x','y']` ?

Без new, без запуска конструктора.

`Object.keys( new A )` работает, но не хочется лишних ифов в конструкторе только для того чтоб вернуть поля.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: @AlexeyTen - `Object.keys( A )` -> `[]`

Comment: А. Без объекта их нельзя нормально получить. Есть хаки, например https://stackoverflow.com/a/72259663/1016033

Comment: где ты хочешь запускать свой код? в конструкторе? или просто принимаешь любой класс и хочешь получить свойства?

Comment: код не в контрукторе основая идея. в статическом методе родительского класса в лучшем случае.

Comment: хотя частично и в конструкторе тоже . чтоб не писать лапшу из this.x=data.x

Comment: непонятно. а что ты вообще хочешь сделать? Зачем тебе получать список полей?

Comment: Да много есть идей. Например, генерировать запрос на SQL MERGE

Comment: но ведь для генерации запроса тебе нужен будет объект чтобы подставить значения?

Comment: @Grundy значения подставляются при выполнении запроса. А запрос можно сформировать один раз при старте. Значений ещё нет

Comment: без создания объекта свойства и поля невозможно будет получить, так как нет явного интерфейса класса и в конструкторе можно добавить любое поле/свойство/метод. Максимум можно из прототипа  класса вытянуть методы и сеттеры/геттеры, которые там хранятся

Comment: тогда проще array через статику прилепить сбоку

Answer (score -1):

Может таким способом попробовать?

```js
 class A
{
  static x = 1;
  static y = 1;

  constructor()
  {
    A.x=0
    A.y=0
  }

  static values()
  {
      return [this.x, this.y];
  }
}

console.log("before ", A.values())

let aNewClass = new A();

console.log("after ",A.values())
```

Comment: Атрибуты не должны быть статическими.